# Add value using calculate field

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, fields-attributes

How can I use "calculate field" in ArcGIS Pro to apply a formula, like below:

if value > 0, insert '-28' so it would automatically insert '-28' in all the entries in the column which meet the criteria

Comment: This may be helpful: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022370

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure you can do this using "calculate field" only. You can use "select layer by attribute" to first select the features where your value is > 0, and then use "calculate field". Your calculation will only apply to the previously selected features.